# Cannot locate file after including it in PHP

Tags: php, include

So I am trying to include some files in PHP and it's not working.

The file I am writing is in the home directory. There is a subdirectory "D1" in the home directory, and in D1, there is another directory, "D2".

Inside D2 there are a bunch of files. I wrote a class file and stored it in D1. It looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once('D2/file1.php');
include_once('D2/file2.php');
//ect

class myClass {
   //class stuff
}
?>
```

So then I write a file inside the home directory like this:

```
<?php
include_once('D1/myclass.php');
?>
```

But when I load this file, I get this:

> Warning: include_once(file1.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/D1/D2/file1.php on line 2

"file1.php" is definitely in that directory, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when including a file, the relative location is relative to the script being called which is the "current working directory". so if script `A.php` includes `./test/B.php` and `B.php` wanted to include a file under `./test/`, it would be relative to `A.php`. You can create an absolute path using `__DIR__` which has the script path and name regardless of where it was included or by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will point to the document root.

B.php example:

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/C.php');
//will include C.php under the same directory as B.php
?>
```

the other option is to add D1 to the includes path in php.ini. this tells php to look in that directory for the file when doing an include.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a linux OS or MAC os you need to be aware of the case for your files, are the `D2`'s capitalized or lower case? etc;

Also I noticed your `class myClass {` line, does that mean THIS file is being included / used by another file? In which case your relative location of the include file may change.

Comment: That is correct, the file that "myClass" is in is the one I am trying to include. Does this mean the relative location of the includes are getting messed up when I include the "myclass.php" file from a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you have a permissions problem. Check that the folders/files have the correct permissions to allow access by the web service.